# Slightly different positioning of graphics compiling with xelatex instead of pdflatex (MiKTeX)

Tags: graphics, xetex, positioning, miktex, includegraphics

**Edited. Truly MWE at the bottom of this post.**

I am having troubles generating the identical PDF outputs from the following Asymptote source code:

```
size(0, 40mm);
draw(unitsquare);
label("$1$", (0.5, 0.5), W + E);
```

using engines `pdflatex` and `xelatex` (compiling it with `-f pdf -tex pdflatex` / `-f pdf -tex xelatex`).

The intermediate source code becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}\ifluatex
\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined\let\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth\fi
\ifx\pdfpageheight\undefined\let\pdfpageheight\paperheight\fi\else
\let\paperwidthsave\paperwidth\let\paperwidth\undefined
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\paperwidth\paperwidthsave\fi
\usepackage{ifluatex}\ifluatex
\ifx\pdfpagewidth\undefined\let\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth\fi
\ifx\pdfpageheight\undefined\let\pdfpageheight\paperheight\fi\else
\let\paperwidthsave\paperwidth\let\paperwidth\undefined
\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\paperwidth\paperwidthsave\fi
\newbox\ASYbox
\newdimen\ASYdimen
\def\ASYprefix{}
\long\def\ASYbase#1#2{\leavevmode\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#1}%\ASYdimen=\ht\ASYbox%
\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#2}\lower\ASYdimen\box\ASYbox}
\long\def\ASYaligned(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5#6#7{\leavevmode%
\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#7}%
\setbox\ASYbox\hbox{\ASYdimen=\ht\ASYbox%
\advance\ASYdimen by\dp\ASYbox\kern#3\wd\ASYbox\raise#4\ASYdimen\box\ASYbox}%
\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#5\wd\ASYbox 0pt\dp\ASYbox 0pt\ht\ASYbox 0pt\box\ASYbox#6}%
\hbox to 0pt{\kern#1pt\raise#2pt\box\ASYbox\hss}}%
\long\def\ASYalignT(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5#6{%
\ASYaligned(#1,#2)(#3,#4){%
\special{pdf:literal q #5 0 0 cm}%
}{%
\special{pdf:literal Q}%
}{#6}}
\long\def\ASYalign(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{\ASYaligned(#1,#2)(#3,#4){}{}{#5}}
\def\ASYraw#1{#1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\pdfpagewidth=113.385827bp
\ifx\pdfhorigin\undefined
\hoffset=-1in
\voffset=-1in
\pdfpageheight=113.385827bp
\else
\pdfhorigin=0bp
\pdfvorigin=0bp
\pdfpageheight=113.385827bp
\fi
\usepackage{everypage}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight=131.385827bp
\textwidth=131.385827bp
\parindent=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\topskip=0pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter%
\let\ASYencoding\f@encoding%
\let\ASYfamily\f@family%
\let\ASYseries\f@series%
\let\ASYshape\f@shape%
\makeatother%
{\catcode`"=12%
\includegraphics{test_0}%
}%
\kern -113.811024pt%
\definecolor{ASYcolor}{gray}{0.000000}\color{ASYcolor}%
\fontsize{12.000000}{14.400000}\selectfont%
\usefont{\ASYencoding}{\ASYfamily}{\ASYseries}{\ASYshape}%
\ASYalign(56.905512,56.905512)(-0.500000,-0.500000){$1$}%
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with `pdflatex` I get the following:

[image]

but compiling it with `xelatex` both the square and the label become misplaced - the square vertically, the label both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

Log (MiKTeX):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 20.6.29) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.7.15)  3 AUG 2020 02:14
entering extended mode
**./xelatex_test_.tex
(xelatex_test_.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls
"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex
.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.st
y"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphic
x.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.
sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphic
s.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.st
y"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\gra
phics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\xet
ex.def"
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
\ASYbox=\box45
\ASYdimen=\dimen137

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\color.s
ty"
Package: color 2019/11/23 v1.2a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\col
or.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 147.
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/everypage\everyp
age.sty"
Package: everypage 2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page
)
("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3back
end-xdvipdfmx.def"
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count171
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box46
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count172
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count173
) (xelatex_test_.aux)
\openout1 = `xelatex_test_.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
7.

("C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
File: test_0.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use test_0.pdf>
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 71.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 71.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 71.
[1

] (xelatex_test_.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 951 strings out of 414039
 14533 string characters out of 2892337
 251271 words of memory out of 3000000
 18651 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 535082 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,5n,25p,225b,104s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on xelatex_test_.pdf (1 page).
```

Apparently, there are no problems within TeX Live but I am using MiKTeX.

Log (TeX Live):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.4.18)  6 AUG 2020 23:15
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**xelatex_test_.tex
(./xelatex_test_.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 105.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
\ASYbox=\box45
\ASYdimen=\dimen137

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2019/11/23 v1.2a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 147.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everypage/everypage.sty
Package: everypage 2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count171
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box46
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count172
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count173
)
(./xelatex_test_.aux)
\openout1 = `xelatex_test_.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
7.
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
File: test_0.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use test_0.pdf>
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 71.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 71.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 71.

[1

] (./xelatex_test_.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 951 strings out of 479417
 15040 string characters out of 5888071
 251779 words of memory out of 5000000
 18506 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535082 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,5n,25p,223b,104s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on xelatex_test_.pdf (1 page).
```

Can someone please help find the root cause?

Ref:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/450a65553e/
- test_0.pdf resource: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/450a65553e/9b76/attachment/test_0.pdf

**EDIT**

I have narrowed down the issue to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{graphicx}%

\begin{document}%
\includegraphics{test_0}%
\end{document}%
```

Comparing the results of MiKTeX's `pdflatex` and `xelatex` I notice both the vertical and horizontal differences. Interestingly, without specifying the `12pt` the horizontal difference is lost but vertical is still present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a miktex bug. It rounds images size to full pt values:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setbox0=\hbox{\XeTeXpdffile example-image-a.pdf\relax}
\showthe\wd0
\showthe\ht0


\setbox0=\hbox{\XeTeXpicfile example-image-a.jpg\relax}
\showthe\wd0
\showthe\ht0

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

gives with miktex:

```
> 321.0pt.
l.18 \showthe\wd0
                 
? 
> 240.0pt.
l.19 \showthe\ht0
                 
? 
> 401.0pt.
l.23 \showthe\wd0
                 
? 
> 301.0pt.
l.24 \showthe\ht0
```

and with texlive

```
> 321.20001pt.
l.18 \showthe\wd0
                 
? 
> 240.9pt.
l.19 \showthe\ht0
                 
? 
> 401.5pt.
l.23 \showthe\wd0
                 
? 
> 301.125pt.
l.24 \showthe\ht0
```

Comment: Thanks! Let's continue the discussion here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/597.